# How to use requestAnimationFrame inside a Class object

Tags: javascript, oop, animation, scope, requestanimationframe

I have a class that takes some coordinate and duration data. I want to use it to animate an `svg`. In more explicit terms, I want to use that data to change `svg` attributes over a time frame.

I'm using a `step` function and `requestAnimationFrame` outside the class:

```
function step(timestamp) {
  if (!start) start = timestamp
  var progress =  timestamp - start;
  var currentX = parseInt(document.querySelector('#start').getAttribute('cx'));
  var moveX =  distancePerFrame(circleMove.totalFrames(), circleMove.xLine);

  document.querySelector('#start').setAttribute('cx', currentX + moveX);
  if (progress < circleMove.duration) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}

var circleMove = new SingleLineAnimation(3000, startXY, endXY)

var start = null

function runProgram() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

I can make it a method, replacing the `circleLine` with `this`. That works fine for the first run through, but when it calls the `this.step` callback a second time, well, we're in a callback black hole and the reference to `this` is broken. Doing the old `self = this` won't work either, once we jump into the callback `this` is undefined(I'm not sure why). Here it is as a method:

```
step(timestamp) {
  var self = this;

  if (!start) start = timestamp
  var progress =  timestamp - start;
  var currentX = parseInt(document.querySelector('#start').getAttribute('cx'));
  var moveX =  distancePerFrame(self.totalFrames(), self.xLine);

  document.querySelector('#start').setAttribute('cx', currentX + moveX);
  if (progress < self.duration) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(self.step);
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to keep the "wiring" inside the Object?

Here's the code that more or less works with the `step` function defined outside the class.

```
class SingleLineAnimation { 
  constructor(duration, startXY, endXY) {
    this.duration = duration;
    this.xLine = [ startXY[0], endXY[0] ];
    this.yLine = [ startXY[1], endXY[1] ];
  }

  totalFrames(framerate = 60) { // Default to 60htz ie, 60 frames per second
    return Math.floor(this.duration * framerate / 1000);
  } 

  frame(progress) {
    return this.totalFrames() - Math.floor((this.duration - progress) / 17 );
  } 
}
```

This will also be inserted into the Class, for now it's just a helper function:

```
function distancePerFrame(totalFrames, startEndPoints) {
  return totalFrames > 0 ? Math.floor(Math.abs(startEndPoints[0] - startEndPoints[1]) / totalFrames) : 0;
}
```

And click a button to...

```
function runProgram() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

Comment: Where and when does `runProgram()` get called? How and where is `SingleLineAnimation` defined?

Comment: How about `distancePerFrame()`?

Comment: What I did just realize it that I can define `requestAnimationFrame` as a prop on the object.

Comment: @icicleking if you've lost your `this` that wouldn't help.  Fortunately that's not the only way to crack this nut.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to bind the `requestAnimationFrame` callback function to a context.   The canonical way of doing this is like this:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this.step.bind(this))
```

but it's not ideal because you're repeatedly calling `.bind` and creating a new function reference over and over, once per frame.

If you had a locally scoped variable set to `this.step.bind(this)` you could pass that and avoid that continual rebinding.

An alternative is this:

```
function animate() {

    var start = performance.now();
    el = document.querySelector('#start');

    // use var self = this if you need to refer to `this` inside `frame()`

    function frame(timestamp) {

        var progress =  timestamp - start;
        var currentX = parseInt(el.getAttribute('cx'));
        var moveX =  distancePerFrame(circleMove.totalFrames(), circleMove.xLine);
        el.setAttribute('cx', currentX + moveX);

        if (progress < circleMove.duration) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
        }
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}
```

i.e. you're setting up the initial state, and then doing the animation within a purely locally scoped function that's called pseudo-recursively by `requestAnimationFrame`.

NB: either version of the code will interact badly if you inadvertently call another function that initiates an animation at the same time.

Comment: You're right that binding each time through seems like a bad idea is a way(the way?) to get the wiring inside the Object, and that that's a bad idea for performance. Executing the ticking within a separate function is probably the way to go.